# pass response to html from controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

I am new to magento. I am setting phtml as layout of the php page.

This way

```
   $this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template','Company_Project',array('template' => 'page/homepage.phtml'));

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    $this->renderLayout();
```

I am getting some info from user in this phtml file. I am doing some database operation on form submit. And then want to use javascript to display message to the user.

Currently i am calling javascript code directly from php page. I know it's not the proper way to do it. But I don't how i can do it by sending response to phtml/html from php and then call javascript from that file.

Any Help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: sooo... your question is?

Comment: how to return response back to html from php controller.